# Strange text appearing in question summaries

Tags: bug, status-norepro, newest-questions

Some questions on the Newest Questions page have strange text included in the question summary (below the question title).

I've noticed this twice today. In both cases the strange text started with the phrase **[Random News**.

After refreshing the page the strange text disappears ...

There is no edit history in the question containing the strange text.

Example below.

> [image]

When opening the question https://superuser.com/questions/929696/autohotkey-doesnt-work-while-i-play-dota-1-anyone-have-any-idea the content appears normal.

> [image]

---

Update:

It's just happened again :/

> [image]

Comment: Are you _sure_ it's not a rogue browser extension/add-on? There was some trouble about a year ago with some extensions that had been bought from their independent developers by a shady outfit that then injected ads. Since the extension already existed the changes were an update and weren't vetted the same as a newly-created extension. It wouldn't surprise me if something like that was happening here.

Comment: It's certainly possible. But I've only ever seen this on StackExchange sites. I have too many extensions (all mainstream) to want to test with them all disabled (especially as I can't repro it on demand) :/ And reloading the page gives the expected text ... next time it happens I will lokk at the page source and see if that gives any clues ...

Comment: Have you inspected the code? How is this added, maybe via some div; check its name or class then and tell there. Also, I don't seem to be able to find anything by goolgling the keywords appearing in your screenshots.

Comment: @nicael On my list next time is see the oddity ;)

Comment: So when you reload the page it's gone?

Comment: @nicael Yes, correct

Comment: Strange; Can you see multiple entries of this heck on one page, or only one per page?

Comment: Seems that the "news provider" differs each time; do they ever repeat?

Comment: @nicael Strange indeed. Only one per page so far, but I haven't checked thoroughly. I'm eagerly waiting for the next one so I can look at the page source.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/888/discussion-between-davidpostill-and-nicael).

Comment: Sounds like you got some weird malware injecting this, try running some anti-malware tool and see.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Full scans done with avast, malwarebyes anti-malware, superantispyware and spybot. Nothing found apart from a handful of tracking cookies and false alerts for nirsoft password utilities.

Comment: hmm.... so really no idea what's going on. Maybe Voodoo?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, I'm waiting for it to happen again to I can look at the page source next time around ;)

Answer (score 4):

Can't reproduce this here...

> [image]

Are you sure there are no extensions or anything on your machine that could be injecting these fun facts into the page?

It's also possible that the user originally copy/pasted that by mistake into the question but removed the text during the grace period. (Edits made within 5 minutes of posting don't leave a revision history trace.)

Comment: Can't you see if there were edits during grace period with your super secret tools as dev? :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure none of my extensions are doing this. I've seen it twice today and I don't think it was the same user (the above user has asked only one question - unless he deleted one). Unfortunately I didn't make any notes the first time I saw it :/

Comment: Slight nitpick: Your screenshot is of the "Newest questions" tab, while the original screenshot behavior was presumably on the "Active questions" tab. I can reproduce the [tag:status-norepro], though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard What a brilliant idea. Why haven't I thought to use the tools... (We don't log grace period edits. Traffic logs do show that the user hit the edit route, but I have no idea what was actually edited.)

Comment: hmm... so most likely user indeed added this by mistake and removed during grace period.

Comment: I am running [SE Additional Optional Features](http://stackapps.com/q/6091) which does modify the se pages display ... but I be surprised if this inserted random news text

Comment: @DavidPostill Yeah, my money is on the user pasting some text in to get past the quality filter and then attempting to ninja-edit until they found a magic combination of text that worked.

Comment: @DavidPostill I Can't see anything in my userscript that should do this - and I can't repro either with the script running - have you tried incognito mode?? You might have a different extension running...

Comment: @AnnaLear It just happened again :/ Question updated. I'm happy for you to ignore this as nobody seems see the problem/repsodue it ;)

Comment: @Sha mistakely spamming?... And also, OP can see this again.